# Need help with previous "Automata / Theory Of Computation" exam question

Tags: automata, finite-automata, context-free

I passed by this question in a previous exam while studying for the "Automata / Theory Of Computation" and I am struggling to find answer. I would appreciate it if someone can help me with it:

This is the question:

a)On the basis of what was covered in class, draw the Venn diagram representing the following sets:

1.REXP: the set of the language given by all regular expressions

2.DFSA: the set of all languages recognized by deterministic FSAs

3.NFSA: the set of all languages recognized by non-deterministic FSAs

4.CFG: the set of all languages generated by context free grammars

5.PDA: the set of all languages recognized by PDAs

Comment: Welcome to the site! We'd be happy to help you, but you have to help us first, by answering some other questions. For instance: What's giving you problems? What parts of the question can you answer immediately? What don't you understand? and so on.

Comment: I suspect the difficulty is with the term *Venn diagram*.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant set-theoritic relations are
$$
\mathsf{REXP} = \mathsf{DFSA} = \mathsf{NFSA} \subsetneq \mathsf{CFG} = \mathsf{PDA}.
$$
The corresponding Venn diagram consists of two circles, one inside the other.